# php prepared statement fails.

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm guessing I'm missing something, but I can't seem to get this statement to work. When I load it into the page I get the white screen of death.

Here is what I'm trying to get to run

```
         $statement = $db-> prepare("INSERT INTO `simplyaccomplished`.`blog_comment` (`ID`, `comment`, `date`, `ip_address`, `valid`, `name`, `blogcomment_ID`) VALUES (NULL, ?, NOW(), ?, 0, ?, ? );");
         $statement -> bind_param("sssi",$comment, $ipaddress, $name , $comment_id);
         $statement -> execute($statement);
         $statement -> close();
```

The weird thing is this runs perfectly

```
         $query = ("INSERT INTO `simplyaccomplished`.`blog_comment` (`ID`, `comment`, `date`, `ip_address`, `valid`, `name`, `blogcomment_ID`) VALUES (NULL,'$comment' , NOW(), '$ipaddress', '0', '$name', '$comment_id');");
         $result =$db->query($query);
```

If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If you get a white screen of death, try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`.

Comment: Good call. Looks like it is Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()

Comment: This is not PDO method - PDO method is bindparan(). You are using mysqli object's bind_param method.

Comment: And `$statement->execute($statement);` looks also redundantly wrong. In PDO you could skip the `->bindParam()` and just pass the parameters as array to `->execute([$comment,$ip,$name]);` as the types are auto-detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDO method you're looking for is named `bindParam`, not `bind_param` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysqli` method,

```
$statement = $db-> prepare("INSERT INTO `simplyaccomplished`.`blog_comment` (`ID`, 
      `comment`, `date`, `ip_address`, `valid`, `name`, `blogcomment_ID`) 
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?)");
$statement -> bind_param("ssssisi",
         null,$comment,NOW(),$ipaddress, 0,$name , $comment_id);
```

Take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [MySqlI](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Since OP's error message referred to a PDOStatement, I'd guess he's not using MySQLi…but maybe you're suggesting he switches?

Comment: @Matchu - Yes May be incorrect call of bindParam of PDO statement.

Comment: I got it!                                                     $statement = $db-> prepare("INSERT INTO `simplyaccomplished`.`blog_comment` (`ID`, `comment`, `date`, `ip_address`, `valid`, `name`, `blogcomment_ID`) VALUES (NULL, ?, NOW(), ?, 0, ?, ?);");
             $statement -> bindvalue(1,$comment);
             $statement -> bindvalue(2, $ipaddress); 
             $statement -> bindvalue(3, $name);
             $statement -> bindvalue(4, $comment_id);             
             $statement -> execute();
             $statement -> closeCursor();